# Laravel request validation not working for postman request

Tags: laravel, validation, multidimensional-array, laravel-7, request-validation

For the following request, when body params are sent as JSON, it always validates the request (as in no validation rule is triggered), but when sent in form-data or form-urlencoded, it passes through validation rules. Is it a limitation with Laravel?

```php
namespace App\Api\Requests\OrganizationUser;

use App\Api\Constants\PlatformRoles;
use Framework\Http\Requests\APIFormRequest;

class CreateNewUserRequest extends APIFormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'bail|required|string|max:255',
            'access' => 'present|array',
            'access.*.access_type' => ['bail', 'sometimes', 'string'],
            'access.*.id' => ['bail', 'sometimes', 'string']
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set postman Header properly:

*Content-Type:* application/json

*Accept:* application/json

Answer (score 2):

couz when you send it as form-data the body structure were changed try to dd your request and see how the request look like.

```
public function rules()
{
   dd($this->request->all());
```